# Celery 'Success' but no results present in Redis

Tags: python, redis, celery

Created a celery app that works in the majority of cases, but there are some cases where the state is marked as a success but when retrieving the result from Redis using AsyncResult(jobid) is marked as 'SUCCESS' but job.get() returns None. How is this possible that it has returned successfully but not returned the result.

Comment: Is Redis also your message broker or are you using something else? Maybe edit your configuration settings/main setup into your question in case someone can spot something

Comment: Redis is just the back end. Rabbit is my message broker

Comment: Could it be simply that under certain circumstances your task really *does* return None?